# Why isn't this ajax form working?

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

```
function ga_script_script_question($form, &$form_state) {
    $form['question'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('Question'),
        '#collapsible' => FALSE, 
        '#collapsed' => FALSE, 
        '#prefix' => '<div id="question-wrapper">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );

    if(isset($form_state['storage']['myflag'])) {
        $form['question']['new_thing'] = array(
            '#markup' => "new thing",
        );
    }

    $form['question']['original_thing'] = array(
        '#markup' => "original thing",
    );

    $form['next_question'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Next question'),
        '#submit' => array('ga_script_script_next_question'),
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'ga_script_script_callback',
            'wrapper' => 'question-wrapper',
        ),
    );

    return $form;
}

function ga_script_script_next_question($form, $form_state) {
    $form_state['storage']['myflag'] = 1;
    $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}

function ga_script_script_callback($form, &$form_state) {
    return $form['question'];
}
```

When I submit this form, nothing happens. I get the little spinning thing next to my submit button, but the contents of question-wrapper are unchanged. It seems like the form is not getting rebuilt.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I just realised I was missing the & in my submit function. It should have looked like this:

```
function ga_script_script_next_question($form, &$form_state) {
}
```

It works fine now.